# Symfony server:run in php Docker container

Tags: php, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I have a php docker container where is my symfony project.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
php-fpm:
    build: ./php
    container_name: php-fpm
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
        - 8448:8448
        - 8000:8000
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:
        - ../app:/var/www/html
    volumes_from:
        - data
    tty: true
    env_file:
        - ./docker.env
    entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
```

I want to launch my symfony project with this command:

```
php bin/console server:run localhost:8000
```

But it's not working when I want to access the url. I have this error message:

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost didn’t send any data.

How can I fix that?

PS: I'm using docker for mac

And  `php bin/console -vvv server:run localhost:8000` outputs:

> [2016-08-06 14:09:53] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   localhost:8000 (Connection refused)
>   {"type":2,"file":"/var/www/html/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"level":28928}
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                       [OK] Server running on http://localhost:8000
> ```
>
> // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
>
> RUN  '/usr/local/bin/php' '-S' 'localhost:8000'
>   '/var/www/html/symfony-test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'

Comment: What `php bin/console -vvv server:run localhost:8000` outputs ?

Comment: run it on all interfaces: `php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Following @Alex Blex answer: It works when you run it on all interfaces.

```
 php bin/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000
```