# Dockerfile in Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I have a symfony 3 project that I'm running using the following command:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

However I have built a docker image of it, that uses the following Dockerfile:

```
  FROM php:7.0-fpm


  WORKDIR /


  ADD . /


  EXPOSE 8000

  ENTRYPOINT php bin/console server:run
```

With entrypoint I was aiming to have the project actually run when I run the docker container.  However whilst I get the correct message saying:

```
   [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

The project is actually not available.  Could someone please show me where I'm going wrong!

Comment: What is "when I run the docker container"? What does "The project is actually not available" mean? Please give more information so we can reproduce.

Comment: You will likely get up to speed a lot faster with an existing PHP/Docker proeject, such as https://phpdocker.io

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Try 0.0.0.0:8000 as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813517/2061624) because you are inside a container.

Comment: @FranckGamess thanks, that worked!

Comment: @Nespony you're welcome